# Delete query with complex filter using Kotlin Exposed

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am creating a deletion query in which I need to call native Postgres functions to filter the records that should be removed.

In summary, the query is as follows: **delete all records that have the start_at column (timestamp) older than 5 days (dynamic parameter for the query)**.

For native SQL, the query would be as follows:

```
delete from my_table t where date_part ('day', (current_date - t.start_at))> = 5
```

In my Kotlin coding, I am not able to implement this query. The examples in the exposed documentation don't have code with more complex filters like that. I know it's something like:

**(1)**

```
transaction {
   MyTable.deleteWhere {
     MyTable.startAt greaterEq ??????
   }
}
```

or

**(2)**

```
transaction {
   exec ("delete query here> = $ {daysToFilter}")
}
```

Is there a way to do this query in code following example (1)?
If not, what would be the best way to do this query?

Sample DataSet:

| id | start_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-01 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 2020-09-02 09:00:00 |
| 3 | 2020-09-03 09:00:00 |
| 4 | 2020-09-04 09:00:00 |

Comment: Note that `where t.created_at < current_date - 120` would be a more efficient query as it could make use of an index on `created_at`

Comment: Expanding on @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion, it would make it trivial to implement in kotlin if you pre-calculate `current_date - 120days` in kotlin beforehand. Either way, it seems that from reading [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/990) basic math should be possible

Comment: @JensV: can't you just have a parameterized query using e.g. `delete from my_table where created_at < current_date - ?`and then pass an integer value? At least that's how it would work in JDBC

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Absolutely, I don't use exposed though and don't know if they have a way of expressing `current_date` for the query

Comment: `current_date` is a SQL keyword. Why would the obfuscation layer need to understand that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You'd need some way to add it to the query. I was just wondering how you'd do that but I found it here: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/ff181e3cfb38b72a007cc05fc7cc80e6ac09318b/exposed-jodatime/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/jodatime/DateFunctions.kt#L12-L19 The documentation of the project seems severely lacking though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final solution was the following:

```
fun my_function(days: Int) {
    val startAt = DateTime.now()
                .withTimeAtStartOfDay()
                .minusDays(days)

    transaction {
        MyTable.deleteWhere {
            MyTable.startAt greaterEq startAt         
        }     
    } 
}
```